# angularjs ng-repeat show all list objects

Tags: angularjs

I have this app which lets users create own events and others to register to those events. When creating event you can have as many questions as you like and you can name the questions as you wish. Those will be asked in the registration. App will fetch the names of the questions from the fields and record them in to the entries.

I am having problems to display a table of people that are going to attend. My app is handling one list:

```
 var events = [{
    Title: 'Summer Festival',
    Date: '12.7.2015',
    Location: 'Moon',
    Description: Fillertxt,
    url: "www.something.com",
    MaxEntries: 10,
    fields: [{
      id: 'choice1',
      name: "Gender"
    }, {
      id: 'choice1',
      name: "Address"
    }],
    entries: []
  },
```

Fields have all the questions and when I add an entry and print it it will show `{"Gender":"rr","Address":"rr"}` in this case.

The problem is that because I cannot foresee the names of those fields I cannot use `ng-repeat` and then just say `<td>{{event.Gender}}<td>`because it might as well be `{{event.lifesmeaning}}`. So how can i display a nice table with the registration info. Can I fetch those names from the fields somehow? I tried nested ng-repeat but didn't got it to work.

Here is also part of the registration page:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <form>
    <div class="border-box">
      <center>
        <h2 class="big">Participate:</h2>

        <div data-ng-hide="!listFull()">The registration for this event is full.</div>
        <div class="form-group" data-ng-hide="listFull()">
          <label for="eventInput">Name</label>
          <input style="width: 200px;" type="text" class="form-control" id="eventInput" data-ng-model="newEntry.name">
        </div>
        <div data-ng-repeat="field in event.fields" data-ng-hide="listFull()">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="{{$index + 1}}">{{field.name}}</label>
            <input style="width: 200px;" type="text" class="form-control" id="{{$index + 1}}" data-ng-model="newEntry[field.name]">
          </div>
        </div>
        <button style="width: 100px;" data-ng-click="addEntry()" class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-hide="listFull()">Save</button>

      </center>
      <br/>
    </div>
  </form>

  <div class="border-box2">
    <h2 class="big" align="center">Who is comming:</h2>

    <p align="center">{{event.MaxEntries}} can participate.</p>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr data-ng-repeat="entry in event.entries">
            <th>{{entry}}</th>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <br/>
    <br/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you still can use {{event[yourFieldName]}}

Comment: What you can do is making an array of objects with veriable field name as well as its value when form is filled. 
what I mean to say is 
    var sample = [ [ { sampleField : sampleValue} ] , [ {     anotherSampleField : anotherSampleValue } ] ]

Comment: I gave {{event[yourFieldName]}} a shot again with two ng-repeats and got it print. Now I'm facing problems with printing the table correctly. Well, I have time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If people are still stumbling upon this post...

### 1. Simple list of objects

So if you have a list/object of objects that will be populated dynamically, like such:

```
var list = [
               {key1: 'value1'},
               {key2: 'value2'}
           ]
```

And more key, value pairs will be added going forward (possibly with a push to the list).

In this case, the table body would be constructed as so

```
     <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="obj in sobjs">
        <td ng-repeat="(key, value) in obj">
          {{key}}
        </td>
        <td ng-repeat="(key, value) in obj">
          {{value}}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
```

### 2. That was simple. Instead if you have a more complex structure as so:

```
var list = [
  {'key1': [
      {
        'skey1':'sval11',
        'skey2':'sval12'
      },
      {
        'skey1': 'sval11a',
        'skey2': 'sval11b'
      }
    ]},
  {'key2': [
      {
        'skey1':'sval21',
        'skey2':'sval22'
      },
      {
        'skey1': 'sval21a',
        'skey2': 'sval21b'
      }
    ]}
]
```

In this case the table body will be constructed as so:

```
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="obj in lobjs">
        <td ng-repeat="(key, value) in obj">
          {{key}}
        </td>
        <td ng-repeat="(key, value) in obj">
          <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>
                  Sub-value 1
                </th>
                <th>
                  Sub-value 2
                </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr ng-repeat="sobj in value">
                <td>
                  {{sobj.skey1}}
                </td>
                <td>
                  {{sobj.skey2}}
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Plunker working code: https://plnkr.co/edit/r4naGBaYAufhD073oXdw?p=preview

Code snippet with the same code below

```js
function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.sobjs = [{
    'key1': 'value1'
  }, {
    'key2': 'value2'
  }]

  $scope.lobjs = [{
    'key1': [{
      'skey1': 'sval11',
      'skey2': 'sval12'
    }, {
      'skey1': 'sval11a',
      'skey2': 'sval11b'
    }]
  }, {
    'key2': [{
      'skey1': 'sval21',
      'skey2': 'sval22'
    }, {
      'skey1': 'sval21a',
      'skey2': 'sval21b'
    }]
  }]
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="">

<head>
  <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.6" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.7" data-semver="1.2.7" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.7/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <h2>Simple List of Objects</h2>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>
            Key
          </th>
          <th>
            Value
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="obj in sobjs">
          <td ng-repeat="(key, value) in obj">
            {{key}}
          </td>
          <td ng-repeat="(key, value) in obj">
            {{value}}
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <h2>List of Objects with a list of objects as values for each key</h2>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>
            Key
          </th>
          <th>
            Value
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="obj in lobjs">
          <td ng-repeat="(key, value) in obj">
            {{key}}
          </td>
          <td ng-repeat="(key, value) in obj">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>
                    Sub-value 1
                  </th>
                  <th>
                    Sub-value 2
                  </th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="sobj in value">
                  <td>
                    {{sobj.skey1}}
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    {{sobj.skey2}}
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Cool! Very useful!

Answer (score 0):

Write an array of arrays and keep both field and value as element of array. Something like this :

```
var sample = [ [ sampleField, sampleValue ], [ anotherSampleField , anotherSampleValue ] ];
```

Now you can iterate using ng-repeat as :

```
<li ng-repeat = "index in sample"> index[0] : index[1]</li>
```